# Property observers (KVO): are they still the way to go?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to use property observers to update my views when a model object changes. I think this is a great non-obtrusive way to do it, especially because the views I need to update are not within reach of the code performing the change.

I simply added an observer like this:

```
someObject.addObserver(observer, forKeyPath:"name", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context:nil)
```

And then implemented this method inside the "observer"

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    // Do my thing
}
```

This iOS observer API feels a bit out-dated for some reason. So I was wondering: is this still the way to go in iOS? Or are there better alternatives nowadays to implement this kind of observer/observable-like pattern?

**EDIT: It looks like property observers (KVO) don't even work with Swift. So either way I need another approach**

Comment: Didn't you want the didSet and willSet methods, as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes I know about didSet and willSet. But that doesn't solve it for me because I don't need to handle the property change inside the same class. I need to handle it somewhere else entirely, inside a view which happens to have the same instance of that object.

Comment: Ok, in this case I'm not sure about what is best pattern.

Comment: As for your note about KVO in Swift, please have a look at [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8) and never forget about the `dynamic` keyword :)

Comment: It turns out that RAC also doesn't work without the dynamic keyword! I couldn't make it work until I saw your comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try something new, that starts from KVO, then opens up a world of possibilities, consider having a look at Functional Reactive Programming and [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa).

Apart from the GitHub repo I linked above (full of [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/tree/master/Documentation)), you can find lots of introductory tutorials on the net, like:

- [Getting Started with ReactiveCocoa](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/getting-started-with-reactivecocoa/)
- [NSHipster - ReactiveCocoa](http://nshipster.com/reactivecocoa/)
- [ReactiveCocoa Tutorial – The Definitive Introduction](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62699/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt1)

This technique has been used successfully in several projects and there are heaps of inspiring code samples you can find online.

Just for reference, a cool real-life project using ReactiveCocoa is the [Artsy Eidolon project](https://github.com/artsy/eidolon).

Comment: I saw a presentation on this once. It looked cool! But I got the impression that this is an "all or nothing" kind of framework. So you either do everything this way or you don't at all. Is it like that? Or can I just use it for one use case and leave the rest of my app as is?

Comment: One nice thing about ReactiveCocoa (RAC) is that you can use it just here and there in an existing app, where you feel confident about it :) You're not required to convert your whole code base and nobody forces you to use the more advanced features. A good starting point, for instance, is having your login screen (as it's usually pretty self-contained) based on RAC, while the rest of your app is written in the style you're most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Property Observers do exist in Swift and are used heavily to observe and act when the property value changes, definitely preferred over KVO.
**Swift 4**

**Example 1**

```
var yourProperty: String = "" {
   didSet {
      updateView() 
   }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
var viewModel: PhotoViewModel {
   didSet {
      collectionView.reloadData()
   }
}
```